# How to save the Home Cover Photo of a LINE profile?

Tags: line

In the upper section of each [LINE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.naver.line.android) user's home screen a background picture is displayed, called *Home Cover Photo* in [LINE's own terms](https://help.line.me/line/android/categoryId/20000181/2/sp?lang=en). How is it possible to save the cover photo of another user?

Comment: Please reopen, this is not a duplicate. Unlike other pictures, the cover photo does not have any download button. Actually, the only way I could imagine would be taking a screenshot (which is tricky as it is half-hidden by UI elements but somehow movable), but somehow might know a better trick.

Answer (score 2):

Home Cover Photos are cached in the following directory:

```
/sdcard/Android/data/jp.naver.line.android/storage/toyboximg/line
```

Rename the extension of files to `.jpg` to view them.